# Use Peano Axioms to prove $(∀m)(∀n)(0 < n ⇒ (∃!q)(∃r)(m = q·n + r∧r < n)) $

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, axioms, peano-axioms

The axioms are given by:

$(∀x)¬(x^+ = 0)$

$(∀x)(∀y)(x+ = y^+ ⇒ x = y)$

Schema: for every expression P and variable symbol x, $P( 0) ⇒ (∀x)(P(x) ⇒ P(x^+)) ⇒ (∀x)P(x)$

$(∀x)(x + 0 = x)$

$(∀x)(∀y)(x + y^+ = (x + y)^+) $

$(∀x)(x.0 =  0)$

$(∀x)(∀y)(x.(y^+) = (x.y) + x)$

And $<$ is defined as an abbreviation for $(∃u)(x + u^+ = y)$

I am asking to prove that  $(∀m)(∀ n)(0 < n ⇒ (∃!q)(∃r)(m = q·n + r∧r < n)) $ using the above axioms, but can hardly think of where to get start. Could someone please give a proof? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Wow, I really hope that this is not your first proof you have to give on the basis of the Peano Axioms, because this is not easy ... typically a first proof would be something much simpler, like $\forall x \forall y x + y = y + x$.  So if you're a beginner with these Peano Axioms, I can understand that you're at a bit of a loss as to how to even start this.

OK, before trying a formal proof on the basis of the Peano Axioms, it makes sense to first get straight on a mathematical proof of why this is so. Here is such a proof:

First, let's prove that there definitely does exist at least one $q$ (and $r$) with the desired property. We can do this by induction over $m$:

Base: $m=0$.  For any $n$, the following holds: $0 = 0 \cdot n + 0$, and of course $0 < n$. That is, we can pick $q = 0$ and $r = 0$.

Step: Let $m$ be arbitrary, and suppose (inductive hypothesis) that for any $n$ there exists a $q$ for which there is an $r$ such that $m = q\cdot n + r \land r < n$. Now let's show that for any $n$ there is a $q'$ for which there is an $r'$ such that $m^+ = q'\cdot n + r' \land r' < n$.

There are really only two cases to consider

Well, if $r^+ < n$, then $m^+ = q \cdot n + r^+ \land r^+ < n$, so set $q' = q$ and $r' = r^+$

If $r^+ = n$, then $m^+ = q^+ \cdot n + 0 \land 0 < n$, so set $q' = q^+$ and $r' = 0$

OK, so this proves existence. Now let's prove uniqueness. We do this using a proof by contradiction:

Suppose you have an $m$ and $n$, $q_1$, and $r_1$, $q_2$, and $r_2$ such that:

$m = q_1 \cdot n + r_1 \land r_1 < n$

$m = q_2 \cdot n + r_2 \land r_2 < n$

and where $q_1 \not = q_2$

Since $q_1 \not = q_2$, we have $q_1 < q_2$ or $q_1 > q_2$

Let's just consider the case $q_1 < q_2$ (the other one is analogous).

So that means $q_2 = q_1 + d$ for some $d > 0$

Since we have that $m = q_2 \cdot n + r_2$

We thus get: $m = (q_1 + d) \cdot n + r_2$

And therefore:

$m = q_1  \cdot n + d \cdot n + r_2$

But since we had that $m = q_1 \cdot n + r_1$, it must be that:

$r_1 = d \cdot n + r_2$

But since $d>0$, we thus get $r_1 \ge n$, which contradicts $r_1 < n$

So, we can't have multiple $q$'s (and $r$'s) for which the equation holds, so that proves uniqueness.

QED

OK, so now that you know what proof to formalize, you still have a ways to go, but at least you have a proof plan.  Now, I would try to first formalize and prove some of the supporting Lemma's. Here are just two of them:

$\forall x \forall y (x < y \lor x = y \lor y < x)$ (Trichotomy)

$\forall x \forall y \forall z (x + y = x + z \rightarrow y = z)$ (Addition (Left) Cancellation)

Both of these are doable to prove from the PA axioms, but still not easy (you'll need to use the induction schema for both of them). But once you have them, the above proof should follow fairly easily, though you want to be careful how to lay out the proof by contradiction for the uniqueness of $q$ inside the universal proof for $m$ and $n$.

Good luck!!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am exactly a beginner and have stucked on it for some time. And now I am quite concerning about this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2201224/how-can-we-modifiy-principle-of-function-de%EF%AC%81nition-to-allow-division-over-the-na  Which is actually why I need to prove this theorem. If possible, could you also please have a look on it? Thanks.

Comment: @Y.X. Yes, I had a feeling ...  That's a really hard exercise for a beginner!  Is this for a course? Anyway, in your other answer you indicate that you would like to use induction for this problem.  But that is really not a good idea. The proof I described above does not use induction and is fairly starightforward ... with the right Lemma's in place.  And some of those Lemma's *do* require induction.  But please do not attempt this very proof by direct induction. Indeed, conceptually, how would the truth of this statement 'propagate' through the numbers? That is not at all clear.

Comment: Yes, it is for a course. Maybe you have clicked on the other question where I said I would use induction. I have seen that where are the difference between these two questions and would not try using induction to prove this statement. The link I gave above is about applying this statement. To construct a way to define division over natural numbers. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2201224/how-can-we-modifiy-principle-of-function-de%EF%AC%81nition-to-allow-division-over-the-na.

Comment: I think in the proof outlined above, we have assumed the existence of $q$. But as a part of definition we should prove the existence of $q$.  May I ask how to show the existence?

Comment: @Bram28 : the negation of what OP wants to prove is "$q$ is not unique or $q$ does not exist".

Comment: @Y.X. (and Max) Yes, good point!  I'll edit the post ... (and of course this means the proof is even more work that it already was) ... oh, and for existence, induction actually *will* be your friend!

Comment: @Y.X.  OK, I updated the proof so it has uniqueness *and* existence .. sorry about that!  But note: I don't use division, and I don't think you want to try to attack this problem by defining some kind of division: that only complicates matters. Again: good luck!