# Verification:How can we modifiy principle of function deﬁnition to allow division over the natural numbers?

Tags: logic, definition, first-order-logic, axioms, peano-axioms

There is a theorem $(∀m)(∀n)(0 < n ⇒ (∃!q)(∃r)(m = q·n + r∧r < n)) $

Now consider to use this theorem to define division over natural number.

The principle of function definition says that:[image]

It seems that we cannot directly use the principle of function definition to define the division over natural number. But where exactly is something wrong here? If we cannot directly apply the principle above to make the definiton. Could someone please tell me why?

And if I really want to do so. That it, use the principle to define  division over the natural numbers. Then could someone please tell me what should I do? How may I modify the principle of function definiton?

EDIT:

Now I think probably I can change the theorem $\vdash (∀x_1)(∀x_2)...(∀x_n)(∃!u)P(u,x_1,x_2,...,x_n) $ into $\vdash (∀x_1)(∀x_2)...(∀x_n)(∃!u)(\exists y_1)(\exists y_2)...(\exists y_m)P(u,x_1,x_2,...,x_n,y_1,y_2,...,y_m) $ with $P$ in $A$.

May I ask if it is correct?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to get clear on how you define division for the natural numbers mathematically, before we should try and formalize this in logic.

I think it is reasonable to use the quotient as your definition, and thus $m$ divided by $n$ (with $n > 0$) would be the $q$ in the formula in the beginning of your post. For $n=0$, we could just stipulate that $m$ divided by $n = 0$ is $0$ (we have to pick something, since we want $\forall x_1 \forall x_2 \exists ! u P(u,x_1,x_2)$)

So, as a general formula $P(u,x_1,x_2)$, the intended meaning of which is: "u is the result of dividing $x_1$ by $x_2$", we can take:

$P(u,x_1,x_2): (x_2 = 0 \land u = 0) \lor \exists r (x_1 = u \cdot x_2 + r \land r < x_2)$

Comment: Oh It seems that I forgot the special case $x_2=0$. But how about use $(∀m)(∀n)(0 < n ⇒ (∃!q)(∃r)(m = q·n + r∧r < n)) $ to ensure that $n\ne 0$? And you see, the principle of function definition seems not to allow multiple out puts, but now I have 2 out puts $q,r$. And this is what the question is about.

Comment: Could you please tell me if I can modify the rule of definition, but not the definiton that is , change the theorem in the principle $\vdash (∀x_1)(∀x_2)...(∀x_n)(∃!u)P(u,x_1,x_2,...,x_n) $ into $\vdash (∀x_1)(∀x_2)...(∀x_n)(∃!u)(\exists y_1)(\exists y_2)...(\exists y_m)P(u,x_1,x_2,...,x_n,y_1,y_2,...,y_m) $ with $P$ in $A$. . To apply $(∀m)(∀n)(0 < n ⇒ (∃!q)(∃r)(m = q·n + r∧r < n)) $ directly to define devision over natural number?

Comment: @Y.X. You are right to worry about having two 'outputs': remember we are trying to define a function here .... A function from $x_1, x_2, ... , x_n$ to $u$. So yes, you really only want one output. And no, you can't change the theorem in the way you indicate ... You really want some formula $P(u, x_1, x_2,  ... x_n)$ so that you can prove $\forall x_1 \forall x_2 ... \forall x_n \exists ! u P(u,x_1,...x_n)$: that is how your text defines this, so you can't deviate from that. Finally, since you are trying to define division, you have two inputs ($x_1$ and $x_2$), and one output $u$.